# Can I simplify my ConcurrentDictionary "add or update" method?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrentdictionary

I have code like this:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DeviceItem> deviceStatesCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DeviceItem>();
private readonly object deviceStatesCacheLock = new object();

public void StoreDeviceStateInCache(Guid guid, DeviceItem deviceState) 
{
        bool added, removed, updated = false;
        
        lock (deviceStatesCacheLock)
        { 
            added = deviceStatesCache.TryAdd(guid, deviceState);

            if (!added) {
                removed = deviceStatesCache.TryRemove(guid, out var _);
                if (removed)
                { 
                    updated = deviceStatesCache.TryAdd(guid, deviceState);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!updated) 
            throw new Exception("WTF: cannot update deviceStatesCache!");
}

private QueryDevicesResponse CreateQueryDevicesResponse()
{
        var deviceItems = new List<DeviceItem>();

        lock (deviceStatesCacheLock)
        {
            foreach (var item in deviceStatesCache)
            {
                deviceItems.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

        var response = new QueryDevicesResponse()
        {
            eventData = new QueryDevicesResponse.EventData()
            {
                devices = deviceItems
            }
        };

        // response.eventSourceGuid = Guid.Empty.ToString();

        return response;
}
```

(edit)

My `lock` here is supposed to work in situations:

1. When another thread tries to get value when item is between remove and insert in `StoreDeviceStateInCache` method (and only this).
2. When another thread started reading all items in `CreateQueryDevicesResponse()` method.

<s>**Can I simplify `StoreDeviceStateInCache()` method a bit?**</s>

<s>I know that AddOrUpdate method exists, but I can't find it helpful since I have to define additional methods and that would look less readable than my code.</s>

looks like [Michael Liu suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687226/1215291) with `deviceStatesCache[guid] = deviceState;` should be enough

**Can I simplify `CreateQueryDevicesResponse()` method a bit and read complete dictionary "atomically"?**

*(WTF stands for "What a Terrible Failure" kind of exception of course)*

Comment: Please explain exactly what your operation is supposed to be doing, and what kind of thread safety you're aiming for.

Comment: One way to simplify the code is to replace the `ConcurrentDictionary` with a normal `Dictionary`. If you have to lock around *any* of the `ConcurrentDictionary`'s members, then you have to lock around *all* of them (otherwise it won't be thread-safe). And in that case all the advantages of the `ConcurrentDictionary` disappear, and you are left with its disadvantages (inconvenient API and synchronization overhead).

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, you want to add a dictionary entry if the key doesn't exist, and replace the dictionary entry if the key exists.

You can accomplish this by using the ConcurrentDictionary's indexer without any additional locking:

```
deviceStatesCache[guid] = deviceState;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AddOrUpdate method of ConcurrentDictionary type to achieve this. something like below

deviceStatesCache.AddOrUpdate(guid, deviceState, (key, value) => deviceState);

Comment: Can you explain what should I put into `key` and `value` from your example?

Comment: @Kamil: `key` and `value` are just arbitrary names for the lambda parameters, whose values in this case are unused. When ConcurrentDictionary invokes the lambda, it will pass the value of `guid` and the existing value of `deviceStatesCache[guid]`, respectively.